# how to variables from one script to another

Tags: powershell

i have 3 AWS scripts, that was made from a former partner no longer in company where each do Check VMS in AWS, Start VM and turn VM off, for security resons now are signed with a certificate and new pass that are like 6 "tokens"

I want to centralize in 1 Script tool, that call each script, but my doubt since lets said i run one to get vms status, put 6 tokens, run the start put 6 tokens then run the turn off run 6 tokens, so is more time entering the tokens than execute the script. and my idea with centralizing is that  from main script use 1 time the 6 tokens in a variable that are read by the AWS scripts

is there a way for that? so that each script reads the tokens from  main new script all from Powershell

Regards.

Some guidance and ideas

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've not included any code to indicate what these tokens are or how they're used/created it's a little hard to judge, but assuming they're simply stored and referenced within each script as variables then there's a couple of options that might work.

Firstly you could declare them as Global variables in the first script, after which they'll continue to exist and be accessible within the current Powershell session, so if one script calls another script, which calls a third script, they're all in the same session and can reference that same Global variable, for instance :

```
$Global:token1="MyToken1"
```

then makes `$token1` a global variable containing the string `"MyToken1"`.

The downside to this is it assumes all your scripts reference those tokens via the same names.

The other option would be to pass the tokens between the scripts using Parameters. So within the scripts being called by the first script (or any subsequent one) you'd add something like the following to the beginning of your script

```
Param(
    
    [parameter(position=0)]
    [string]$token1,

    [parameter(position=1)]
    [string]$token2,

    [parameter(position=2)]
    [string]$token3,

    [parameter(position=3)]
    [string]$tokens4,

    [parameter(position=4)]
    [string]$token5,

    [parameter(position=5)]
    [string]$token6
)
```

and then call that script (lets call it MySecondScript.ps1) using the following

```
& C:\Scripts\MySecondScript.ps1 $token1 $token2 $token3 $token4 $token5 $token6
```

This way the first script can pass those six tokens to the second script, and that second script is now able to use those values. Advantage of this is that the variable names don't have to match, as it's purely positional, so the first entry in the Param statement can have a different name to the first entry passed to the script, they just need to mean/do the same thing to make sense.

Comment: thanks for your reply. ill try that. sadly as per privacy i cant share code.